# Install EMC12c Configuration Assistant Repository has Failed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My installation stop at 52% and it said Configuration Assistant "Repository Configuration" has Failed
This is my log

```
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The command run for transx is E:\app\TrongNhan\mw\oms\sysman\admin\emdrep\bin\RepManager.bat -connect (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example.trongnhan185.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=db12c))) -action transx  -repos_user SYSMAN -dbUser SYS -mwHome E:\app\TrongNhan\mw -mwOraHome E:\app\TrongNhan\mw\oms
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:processing arguments 
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:compiling arguments for validation
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Enter SYSMAN user password :
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Verify:
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms: Enter password for: SYSMAN
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms: process_id:5twvpe4i89xj
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:[Initializing the EM RCU Runner, Running the Schema Action, Schema Action Completed Successfully]
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:************
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The transx command execution is completed with the status 0
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:process_id:
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The Process ID: [] does not exist.  Either it has been completed, or this is not the executing JVM
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The plug-in Repository Configuration has failed its perform method
```

What step i should do now , i have searched google but still cannot find solution

Comment: did you try to run it again ? it looks like the process died somehow.

Comment: You mean , i need to cancel and install again ?

Comment: yes, I mean that. for the log it looks like something has died, because there are no errors or exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with your repository database. Maybe you try to install em12c in a released of oracle DB which is not certified with that. you could try with the other EM like EM 13 or use the following DB releases like ..
*Oracle 11.2.0.3.0
*Oracle 11.2.0.2.0
*Oracle 11.2.0.1.0
*Oracle 11.1.0.7.0
*Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 etc.
Or there could have other OS release issue. you better check the prerequisites from link below....
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/install_em_exist_db.htm#EMBSC162